# building cxref on windows

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to build CXREF on windows, and the build fails.

1. Has anyone successfully built CXREF recently or is is hopelessly out of date?
2. Here is the specific problem which occurs doing the "make"

```
$ make
cd cpp   && /usr/bin/make programs
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/INSTALL/cxref-1.6e/cpp'
./cxref-cpp-configure gcc -o cxref-cpp.defines
gcc  cccp.o cexp.o prefix.o version.o -o cxref-cpp
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/INSTALL/cxref-1.6e/cpp'
cd src   && /usr/bin/make programs
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/INSTALL/cxref-1.6e/src'
gcc -c  -g -O2 latex-style.c -o latex-style.o -I. -I.
latex-style.c:5:1: warning: missing terminating " character
    5 | "%
      | ^
latex-style.c:5:1: error: missing terminating " character
    5 | "%
      | ^~
latex-style.c:6:1: warning: missing terminating " character
```

Indeed the latex-style.c file, which apparently is generated is wrong since the latex_fonts_style array of string has a list of string with an opening " and no closing ".

Here is the output of the configure step

```
$ ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for perl... perl
checking for latex... no
checking for dvips... no
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking malloc.h usability... yes
checking malloc.h presence... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strstr... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating query/Makefile
config.status: creating src/autoconfig.h
config.status: src/autoconfig.h is unchanged
=== configuring in cpp (/c/INSTALL/cxref-1.6e/cpp)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -p
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/wait.h usability... yes
checking sys/wait.h presence... yes
checking for sys/wait.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking for bcmp... yes
checking for bcopy... yes
checking for bzero... yes
checking for index... yes
checking for rindex... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strsignal... yes
checking if installed gcc is new enough to use instead of cxref-cpp... yes
checking if installed gcc preserves comments after define statements... no, using cxref-cpp
checking if installed gcc preserves comments after include statements... no, using cxref-cpp
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating autoconfig.h
config.status: autoconfig.h is unchanged
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating cxref-cpp-configure
config.status: creating autoconfig.h
config.status: autoconfig.h is unchanged
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems like Cxref code contains at least one call to `fork()`. That won't work on native Windows. It may work with cygwin though.

Comment: I ran this on cygwin - note that the latex-style.c file which I understand is generated, has syntax (unterminated strings) - I doubt if that is  because of a fork()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to build cxref against MinGW-w64.

My recipe can be found here:

- https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/cxref.winlib

The recipes for the dependencies can be found here:

- https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/sys_wait_h.winlib
- https://github.com/brechtsanders/winlibs_recipes/blob/main/recipes/win32-fork.winlib